# СПП с придаточным условия?

Tags: спп

> Если кто умрет, я тебя рядом закопаю.

Расчленённой структуры СПП, придаточное условия.

- придаточная часть - *если кто умрет* (союз если);
- главная часть - *я тебя рядом закопаю*.

Верно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы верно рассуждаете. Придаточная часть предшествует главной.